# Automatic App Updates not in the Background anymore since iOS 10

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore, software-update, multitasking

Before updating to iOS 10, I never actively saw the updates happen (the icon going dark, etc), apparently they always happened during the night or something.

Since updating to iOS 10, every morning when I first look at my phone, I see various apps starting to download updates at the same time, which I find pretty unnerving.

iOS 10.0.2 14A456 on iPhone 5S ME435DN/A. I always had Automatic App Updates activated, and never touched the setting. I do not turn my iPhone off during the night, and do not activate night mode or power saving mode. Just Night Shift.

Anyone else noticed this as well? Is there anything I could do?

Thanks,
-M

Comment: First thing, I would upgrade to iOS 10.1. Second, is your phone plugged in during the night, and is it within range of Wi-Fi?

Comment: I see this all the time on my iPad mini 4, it is plugged in all day and in Wifi range, and when I first pick it up to use it after unlock and unplugging , apps start updating. On 10.1.1 currently.

Comment: I have the same issue. Happens to my iPhone and iPad. Both have the most recent iOS. And both are plugged in at night.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be happening to you for a number of reasons:

- iOS 10 has determined that you do not use the updating apps at that time of day, so it is updating them during use to be more efficient
- iOS may also have determined that this time of day and network are when you have the fastest connection.
- If you use Airplane Mode at night (for faster charging and no notifications), it can't update apps at night.
- Or there's a software glitch.

Answer (score 0):

Background update is not working at all on iOS 10.x regardless what internet connection you have, charging status or hardware version.

I am pretty sure Apple knows about it but does nothing because pushing updates costs a lot of money.

I have about 100-200 apps, probably average is 40-50 but with billions pf devices you can easily imagine the bandwidth.

I think that they will bring it back only for incremental updates of recently used apps.